# Mac check in GCM failed after recompiling with apktool

Tags: java, android, encryption, bouncycastle, apktool

I have an android application that uses `BouncyCastle` for encryption and decryption. It has a database that there are some string in it that encrypted with BouncyCastle, I need to decompile that and get some decryption from that, I'm doing this with `apktool` and it gives me success decompile, I'm changing some codes and add log.d to it to use to decrypt it and then after compile that, it successfully compiled, Now while I'm using it and I wanna try to get log from it to know what is that string, it says `mac check in GCM failed`. what should I do?

below the codes of that application:

the text to decrypt:

`IBbdPw==`

for encryption:

```
public static int KeyBitSize = 16;
public static int MacBitSize = 32;
public static int NonceBitSize = 16;
public static String encrypt(String str, byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) {
    String str2 = "";
    try {
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        GCMBlockCipher gCMBlockCipher = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
        gCMBlockCipher.init(true, new AEADParameters(new KeyParameter(bArr), MacBitSize, bArr2, null));
        byte[] bArr3 = new byte[gCMBlockCipher.getOutputSize(bytes.length)];
        gCMBlockCipher.doFinal(bArr3, gCMBlockCipher.processBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length, bArr3, 0));
        return Base64.encodeToString(bArr3, 0);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | DataLengthException | InvalidCipherTextException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return str2;
    }
}
```

for decryption:

```
public static String decrypt(String str, byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) {
    String str2 = "";
    try {
        byte[] decode = Base64.decode(str, 0);
        GCMBlockCipher gCMBlockCipher = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
        gCMBlockCipher.init(false, new AEADParameters(new KeyParameter(bArr), MacBitSize, bArr2, null));
        byte[] bArr3 = new byte[gCMBlockCipher.getOutputSize(decode.length)];
        gCMBlockCipher.doFinal(bArr3, gCMBlockCipher.processBytes(decode, 0, decode.length, bArr3, 0));
        return new String(bArr3, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | DataLengthException | InvalidCipherTextException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return str2;
    }
}
```

Updated:

it is using the code like below to decrypt:

```
byte[] HexToByte(String str) {
        int length = str.length();
        byte[] bArr = new byte[(length / 2)];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2) {
            bArr[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(str.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return bArr;
    }

String arg_1="IBbdPw==";
String arg_2="C6704D668D64DD012A86858C36F35D46F3";
String arg_3="58EB2DB3E1063FC93A";
decrypt(arg_1, HexToByte(arg_2.substring(0, 32)), HexToByte(arg_3.substring(0, 16)));
```

while arg_2 is changing while application run by its sign key

Comment: That ciphertext you want to decrypt cannot have been produced with those parameters since it's only 32-bits in length.

Comment: Can you explain more, please? is there any way to find `barr` and barr2? I have both of them, but `barr` is changing with application sign key, I think it is because of that, is there any way to find `barr`?

Comment: `barr`   = `C6704D668D64DD012A86858C36F35D46`
`bArr2` = `58EB2DB3E1063FC9`
but `barr` is changing with sign key with .so library. @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk

Comment: I have to reinterpret your constants for it to make any sense. The only sensible meaning is that the key size is 16 **bytes**, the nonce size is 16 **bytes**, and the mac size is indeed 32 **bits**. `IBbdPw==`, when base-64 decoded, is only 32 bits, but even with no plaintext (in which case this would be AES-GMAC) should be 20 bytes, thus 20 bytes is the minimum length of valid ciphertext. 16 byte nonce + 4 byte MAC = 20 bytes.

Comment: ah, sorry I updated my question, I added how it is decrypting @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk the arg_2 is changing by .so library that inside application and it is made by CPP or c language, I found that it is changing that arg with an application sign key

Comment: I know the `arg_3`is correct but `arg_2` is not correct and its made with my sign key, and I know it is because of that it can not to decrypt because `arg_2` is not correct, I'm trying to find a way to find `arg_2`, do you think is it possible? @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk